# SplashScreen sin animacion de salida en Flutter

Tags: flutter, programación-móvil, splash

Estoy tratando de hacer un SlashScreen con animated_splash_screen, sin embargo cuando cambia a la siguiente pantalla(LoginScreen) no hay animación. Como puedo hacer que la animación entre el splash y mi LoginScreen sea un fade. El splash y el login ambos son StatefulWidget

Este es codigo que uso para el splash:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSplashScreen(
        splash: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo.svg',
          semanticsLabel: 'Logo',
          color: const Color(0xff424242),
        ),
        duration: 1500,
        splashTransition: SplashTransition.fadeTransition,
        nextScreen: const LoginPage());
  }
```

Comment: Podrías agregar tu LoginPage? tienes algún setState al inicio o algo?

Comment: y otra pregunta, que versión del package estás usando? Acabo de probar el ejemplo que trae ese package y me funciona bien

Comment: Es la ultima versión 1.2.0, y mi login básicamente es la primera viste que se genera cuando creas un proyecto en flutter, solo que la he separado en otro archivo dart `State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPage();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando el package, hay un parámetro que no le estás enviando, el cual es el `pageTransitionType`, por default usa la animación bottom to top, quizás por eso no lo notas.

```dart
transitionType: pageTransitionType ?? PageTransitionType.bottomToTop,
```

`splashTransition` es la transición cuando aparece el Splash, no cuando se mueva a la otra pantalla, para eso está el `transitionType`.

Agrégale

```dart
pageTransitionType: PageTransitionType.fade
```

No te olvides de importar

```dart
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
```

Ya que veo ese package está mal implementado.

Te recomiendo que veas esta charla que di hace poco, crear un splash screen es de lo más sencillo y no veo la necesidad de usar paquetes : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5X-0PATmd2Q

**UPDATE FINAL**

Luego de revisar lo que mencionas, en efecto, hay un bug en la versión 2.10.1, no he podido reproducir el problema con Flutter 2.8.1.

Aquí hay un issue similar https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75973

Si logré hacer que funcione cuando hago mi propio Splash screen y le aumento el tiempo de transición(por algún motivo el bug lo acelera).
El tiempo de transición del package que usa es de 300ms por defecto y no se puede cambiar, lo cual me parece malo, ya que eso debería ser personalizable.

Le puse 1 segundo, así quedaría tu código:

```dart
class SplashPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashPage> createState() => _SplashPageState();
}

class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  Future<void> _waitForSplash() async {
    // Tiempo de espera de tu splash
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500));
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      PageRouteBuilder(
        // Tiempo que demora la animación al mostrar el LOGIN
        transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: const LoginPage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _waitForSplash();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      body: Center(
        child: SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/logo.svg',
          semanticsLabel: 'Logo',
          color: const Color(0xff424242),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agregué lo que me dijiste pero sigue igual, no hay animacion ni con `PageTransitionType.bottomToTop` ni con `PageTransitionType.fade`

Comment: probaste el ejemplo del package? si te funciona el ejemplo, entonces necesitas agregar más código a tu pregunta para ver donde está la falla.

Comment: Acabo de subir mi código a github https://github.com/luis073094/appmovil_uss muy agradecido con tu ayuda. Las vistas son splashppage.dart y loginpage.dart

Comment: veo que si está haciendo la animación, pero lo hace muy rápido, a 300ms cuando va hacia la otra página, mira este tip, aplicalo para que veas que si se anima : https://www.youtube.com/shorts/r7k3wDsAm68   , siendo sincero, ese package de splash screen es un desastre, mira el video que te deje en el post y has tu propio splash screen en unos segundos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Comment: acabo de descubrir que lo que quita la animacion son mis widgets TextFormField personalizados, cuando los elimino de mi loginpage, la animacion se aprecia con normalidad. No tengo idea de que es lo que tienen mis TextFormField  que dañan la animacion

Comment: revisa la version de flutter , yo probe con 2.8.1 y va bien

Comment: listo, acabo de actualizar mi post, espero te funcione, si es así, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como aceptada :)